# bundle exec rake snorby:setup - error rake aborted! invalid hash

Tags: ruby

While executing below command to setup the snorby on ruby on rails, i get the error: rake aborted! invalid hash. Pls help

#bundle exec rake snorby:setup

#Jammit Warning: Asset compression disabled -- Java unavailable.
No time_zone specified in snorby_config.yml; detected time_zone: Asia/Kolkata
750d6d911891ab576bdbc6b1c4dc5ecf73cb95fd145ab7b16194636094daa3b4ba42b01c05d991c8c174919162e00152a129c645b1e0508850042cf224f165af
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 1007 (HY000) at line 1: Can't create database 'snorby'; database exists
[datamapper] Finished auto_upgrade! for :default repository 'snorby'
rake aborted!
invalid hash

Tasks: TOP => db:seed
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

Below are the versions currently used:

#ruby 1.9.3p551 (2014-11-13 revision 48406) [x86_64-linux]

#Bundler version 1.9.3

#Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (focal)

Comment: Please add a minimum, reproducible example of the code being run.

Answer (score 1):

Modifying the entries in seeds.rb file as given below, the error has been resolved. In the seeds.rb changed the line for Default user setup from

User.create(:name => 'Administrator', :email => 'snorby@snorby.org', :password => 'snorby', :password_confirmation => 'snorby', :admin => true) if User.all.blank?

To
User.create(:name => 'Administrator', :email => 'snorby@snorby.org', :encrypted_password => 'snorby', :password_confirmation => 'snorby', :admin => true) if User.all.blank?

i.e the :password was changed to :encrypted_password